# How to lock another videos until the first video is not played?

Tags: javascript, html, wordpress, video

Is there any way to lock (disable the video) the other videos i.e. video2, video3, ...etc until the first video i.e video1 is not play.

The video thumbnails should display at the top of video container like tabs. By clicking on tabs the video should play in below container one by one. The second video tab should be disable until the first tab video is not played.  When the second tab video is played it should unlock the third tab video and so on.

Comment: yes, it is possible to do with some code - have you tried any?

Comment: Yes i have tried many codes but none of them works for me. Actually i am new to coding so i don't have much knowledge about this.

Comment: SO is not a code writing service, so to reduce the chances of having the question closed, how about you show your *best* attempt